# facing complete ubuntu freeze with rtl871x

Tags: wireless, freeze

what is rlt871x? after almost getting all the info from forums , when i check my /var/log/syslog i found that there is something issue with my wifi driver which is causing freeze. the syslog is completely filled with rtl871x and i'm using rtl8188fu, i have blacklisted the default one using this `one echo 'alias usb:v0BDApF179d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin* rtl8188fu' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu-blacklist.conf`when installing from here https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu#disable-power-management

specs:
8GB RAM, SWAP MEM: 2.1GB, 1.3TB , 11TH GEN I5 , GRAPHICS: NVIDIA CORP. GK208B[GeForceGT 730]

kernel version: 6.2.0-34-generic

firmware files:
[image]

never faced any issue of freezing with dual booted window.

i think it's not disabling the rtl871x which is causing the freeze maybe. the freezing is randomly and can freeze even when no application opened.

running `lsusb`:
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter

running lsmod:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEdw3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF511.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km3k1.png)

running `cat /var/log/syslog`:
[image]

this is how somewhat my log looks like after freeze as well.

running `sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl` before unloading rtl8188fu:
[image]

running `sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl` after loading rtl8xxxu:
it was huge so i'm only posting first and last part of it.
[image]

[image]

CPU USAGE AND FAN NOISE ISSUE DUE TO WIFI DRIVER (when seeing videos):
running `htop`:
[image]

running `sensors`:
[image]

normally `sensors`:
[image]

Comment: Your file above blacklists nothing. Which modules are loaded? `lsmod` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: post edited with adding lsmod related images

Comment: We don't see any extraneous Realtek wireless drivers loaded here; only rtl8188fu. Please edit your question to show the exact rtl871x error in syslog.

Comment: What is your kernel version? `uname -r` In version 6.2-xx and later, your device is covered by the native driver *rtl8xxxu*. Did you try that first?

Comment: 6.2.0-34-generic, when i installed ubuntu , in settings the wifi option showed - "no wifi adapter found" than i installed the driver rtl8188fu master and deleted that becuase i think i haven't configured it than reinstalled and configured using the github link i provided. i think i have downloaded it (rtl8188fu) thrice

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8188fu` and then: `sudo modprobe rtl8xxxu` and then post: `sudo dmesg | grep -i rtl`

Comment: my syslog have different output when saw after loading rtl8xxxu should i post it. what if i try using rtl8xxxu for  day to check if it freezes how can i do so, like with the above command it will only load temporarily isn't it?

Comment: The command above will persist until a reboot. If you reboot, redo the sequence. If you wish to make it permanent, as I suspect, I'll be pleased to give instructions in an answer.

Comment: Please note that the error messages ended as you loaded rtl8xxxu at timestamp 365.26xx. All previous messages are associated with rtl8188fu.

Comment: it worked! thank u so much, today whole day i used rtl8xxxu after every reboot and there was no freeze also i found another problem associated with it which got little solved here i.e. earlier with rtl8188fu when i watch any sort of videos on yt or social media the cpu usage gets higher and my fan starts runnings faster but using this rtl8xxxu cpu usage is there but fan noise is less ,comparatively . I have posted some screenshots for more info can u plz answer the two parts 1st is fan noise and usage and 2nd is permanently using rtl8xxxu and deleting the rtl8188fu

Comment: The fan noise is a different issue, likely related to graphics. After switching to rtl8xxxu, please start a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will have better luck with the native *rtl8xxxu* driver. If you blacklisted it, as you implied in your question, remove the blacklist.

Remove the needless /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu-blacklist.conf file:

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu-blacklist.conf
```

Blacklist rtl8188fu:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8188fu" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot.